# way to restrict File type in AEM pathBrowser

Tags: aem

I have requirement to restrict the file types when using the touchUI field,

granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser.

There is a feature for pathfield,

regex :/.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
 regexText : "Please choose a correct file"

which is not working for pathBrowser, TouchUI field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a predicate class on OSGI bundle package where it restricts the file types. The java class,

```
package com.mec.core.utils;

import com.day.cq.commons.predicate.AbstractResourcePredicate;
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;


@Component(label = "Dam Image Predicate",
description = "This predicate is used to display only JPG and PNG files in the pathfield")
@Service(value = Predicate.class)
@Properties({@Property(label = "Predicate Name", name = "predicate.name", value = "damimagepredicate",
propertyPrivate = true)})
public class DamImagePredicate extends AbstractResourcePredicate {
    private static final String REP_ACL = "rep:ACL";
    private static final String JCR_CONTENT = "jcr:content";
    private static final String JCR_PRIMARYTYPE = "jcr:primaryType";
    private static final String DAM_ASSET = "dam:Asset";
    private static final String PNG = ".png";
    private static final String JPG = ".jpg";
    private static final String JPEG = ".jpeg";
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Resource resource) {
        if(null!= resource){
                    ValueMap valueMap = resource.getValueMap();
                    String primaryType = valueMap.get(JCR_PRIMARYTYPE,String.class);
                    if(null!=primaryType && !primaryType.isEmpty()){
                        if(primaryType.equalsIgnoreCase(REP_ACL)){
                            return false;
                        }
                        if(resource.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(JCR_CONTENT)){
                            return false;
                        }
                        if(primaryType.equalsIgnoreCase(DAM_ASSET)){
                            String resourceName = resource.getName();
                            if(null!=resourceName && !resourceName.isEmpty()){
                                if(resourceName.lastIndexOf(".")>-1){
                                    String extension = resourceName.substring(resourceName.lastIndexOf("."), resourceName.length());
                                    if(null!=extension && !extension.isEmpty()){
                                        if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(PNG) || extension.equalsIgnoreCase(JPG) || extension.equalsIgnoreCase(JPEG)){
                                            return true;
                                        }else{
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can do client side restriction in your touch UI component to restrict user from posting other types of file. I would not suggest creating something like this for your use case.

Comment: The client side restriction is with "regex" that too only for classic UI. I dont find any such solutions for TouchUI. Please suggest me if any. @RajeshPantula

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might work for you:

http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2016/04/aem-62-touch-ui-path-browser-filter-for-autocomplete-and-picker-results.html